# How to hide content(like text, radio button, and submit button) Popup window after Clicking on submit and display new content in the same popup?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, popup

How to hide content(like text, radio button, and submit button) in Popup window after Clicking on submit and display new content(text, radio button,submit button) in the same popup window?

ex.,
PopUp Window:

```
<b>Question 1 : </b> Vanessa and Brett had been arguing about their perceived 
proclivity to spend for hours together. What word describes the couple's predicament? <br>
<form name="quest" method="POST" action="">
  <p><input type="radio" value="Wrong" name="ans">Demarche </p>
  <p><input type="radio" value="Correct" name="ans">Impasse </p>

  <p><input type="radio" value="Wrong" name="ans">Mélange </p>
  <p><input type="radio" value="Wrong" name="ans">tête-à-tête </p>

<input type="submit" name="NEXT" value="Next">
</form>
```

After Clicking on Next Button should hide above form and display next form,...

```
<b>Question 2 : </b> Vanessa and Brett had been arguing about their perceived 
proclivity to spend for hours together. What word describes the couple's predicament? <br>
<form name="quest" method="POST" action="">
  <p><input type="radio" value="Wrong" name="ans">Demarche </p>
  <p><input type="radio" value="Correct" name="ans">Impasse </p>

  <p><input type="radio" value="Wrong" name="ans">Mélange </p>
  <p><input type="radio" value="Wrong" name="ans">tête-à-tête </p>

<input type="submit" name="NEXT" value="Next">
</form>
```

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: _“After Clicking on Next Button should hide above form and display next form”_ – well then have the server-side script that you are sending the form data to output a new HTML document that contains the second form …

Comment: can you give code ex for that,.....

Comment: first step : prevent page from reloading when clicking on NEXT button

Comment: must you add id for each form and when click a next button at that time  hide first form and show next form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways, one way to achive this is to use JSON data for getting different questions. And through Jquery/javascript you can frame the forms while clicking on next button.
This will be a best way than using just "hide-show"